# Using DeMorgan’s rule ....

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Using DeMorgan’s rule, state the negation of the statement: “Mary is a musician
and she plays chess.”
Answer
Let m stand for “Mary is a musician” and let c stand for “she plays chess”.
then the answer is  (~M) ^ (~C)

Comment: No.  Close but try again.  *Hint:* What does DeMorgan's rule state about the negation of a conjunction?

Comment: See [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bare bones translation key might be

$M:\;$ Mary is a musician\; $\;C:\;$ Mary plays chess.

Then statement expressed in propositional logic is $M \land C.$

It's negation is $$\lnot(M \land C)$$

This essentially means: "It is ***not*** the case that ***both*** (Mary is a musician and Mary plays chess.)"

Now, using DeMorgan's: $$\lnot (M \land C) \equiv \lnot M \lor \lnot C$$

"It is ***not*** the case that ***both*** (Mary is a musician and Mary plays chess)" therefore means :

"Mary is not a musician, OR Mary does not play chess."

Answer (score 2):

Your original statement in logic is $m\wedge c$.

The negation (using De Morgan's Rule) is $\neg(m\wedge c)\equiv \neg m\vee\neg c$.

This can be written in English as "Either Mary is not a musician **or** she does not play chess".